# Can PCA be performed on ordinal and numeric variables separately and combined for further analysis?

Tags: pca, ordinal-data

I have a mixed dataset containing 3 ordinal and 6 numeric type variables. The numeric variables are clearly correlated and the ordinal variables also have some sort of correlation between them. My objective is to project the dataset onto uncorrelated low dimensional space(dimension < 9) to use them for regression etc.

Now, I see 3 possibilites here:

1. Perform Categorical PCA(CATPCA) [Nonlinear principal components analysis: Introduction and application](https://openaccess.leidenuniv.nl/bitstream/handle/1887/12386/Chapter2.pdf?sequence=10) on ordinal variables; use the resulting scores alongside the scores of conventional PCA on numeric variables as explanatory variables in regression.
2. As CATPCA can't accept numeric variables, convert the numeric variables to ordinal and then perform CATPCA. Then use the resulting scores in regression.
3. Use the Polychoric(for ordinal) and Pearson(for numeric) correlations between the variables in conventional PCA. Then use the resulting scores in regression.

Now my problem is that, I can't figure out if there will arise any difference between the three approaches. If there might exist any differences, how can it be mathematically justified? Thanks!

Comment: What's CATPCA? Sounds like an unexplained command, function or routine in some unexplained software. More crucially, I can't see that the scores on quite separate analyses have any relation that makes them comparable. Why do you want to use any flavour of PCA in the first place? What is the aim of your project?

Comment: Sorry @NickCox, I just edited the question. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: I'd proceed directly to regression. That way, what kinds of PCA to use is completely avoided as a red herring. In this kind of situation your PCs are not easier to think about, nor do they have any real analytical virtues compared with your potential predictors.

Comment: Please search for CATPCA on this site, to read. It does allow numeric variables, it doesn't accept true continuous values, it expects numeric vars as discrete, integers. You may discretize a continuous range into, say, 20 or more bins. Then use the mix of these numeric and of ordinal vars.

Comment: Yes of course. By numeric, I meant continuous. But I wanted to know if there will be any differences between the approaches ?

Comment: Appr1 is inacceptable if you wanted to extract PCs from a combination of numeric and ordinal variables. Appr2 is not needed, since both numeric discretized vars and ordinal vars can be taken together: CATPCA will treat these and those differently. Use that "Appr2a". Appr3 is possible but is problematic to compute PCscores.